# python looping socket connections

Tags: python, sockets

Question regarding the python socket package

My goal is to create a simple network port scanner. This is the basic idea:

```
#List of ports to scan
ports = [20,21,22,23,25,80]

#dictionary of port statuses
port_status = {}

#Create socket:
MY_SOCK = s.socket(s.AF_INET, s.SOCK_STREAM)

#For loop to scan each port
for port in ports:
    TARGET = ("192.168.12.123", port)
    
    #If connection is successful, result should be int 0
    result = MY_SOCK.connect_ex(TARGET)

    #save port and status as key/pair value
    port_status[port] = result

    #Terminate socket
    MY_SOCK.shutdown(s.SHUT_RDWR)
    MY_SOCK.close()
```

I am having an issue that after the first successful socket connection, it doesn't restart properly for the following sockets.

With the syntax shown above, I get thrown an OSerror

if I don't do a shutdown, it makes one successful connection then doesn't connect to the following ports.

There must be something wrong with my closing of the socket.

Any advice? Many thanks

Comment: "opening" a socket is at the time of the creation. Just move MY_SOCK into the loop to always use a fresh one

Comment: You're probably on the right path, but I tried it and it still throws an OSerror. This is what I get: OSError: [WinError 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied

Comment: Did you check what line fails? I believe it fails because .connect_ex failed but you try to shutdown, so it says you have no connection. This means it never was "after first successful socket connection, it doesnt restart properly", it was "if it fails, it crashes"

Comment: Create a new socket for each attempt.

Answer (score 0):

By running it line by line outside the loop, I managed to pinpoint the problem.

The issue is that if a connection fails, it throws an error because it could not terminate a failed connection

I solved it (incorporating h4z3's advice to move the socket creation into the for loop) in the following way:

```
for port in ports:
    MY_SOCK = s.socket(s.AF_INET, s.SOCK_STREAM)
    TARGET = ("192.168.12.123", port)
    result = MY_SOCK.connect_ex(TARGET)
    port_status[port] = result

    #Only attempt to close connection if connection was successful (== 0)
    if result == 0:
        MY_SOCK.shutdown(s.SHUT_RDWR)
        MY_SOCK.close()
```

Thanks for the assistance